# How can I use the require-js text-plugin with karma

Tags: requirejs, karma-runner, requirejs-text

I am trying to get the `require-js`  `text plugin` to work with the `karma-testrunner`
I downloaded both with npm. I got karma working with requirejs, it is only the text-plugin that is making me some trouble.

When I add the text.js file to the files that karma serves I get a mismatch Error for it:

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (module) {
   //code from text plugin
```

If I don't serve the file with the text-plugin or exclude in karma.conf it I get a script Error from requirejs
(and a karma Warning: 404/base/text.js)

```
 Uncaught Error: Script error for: text
```

I added the following to my require config file:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
    text: './text.js'  //also tried text.js

  }
 })
```

but that doesn't seem to change anything

I have the dependency on the text plugin and template declared like this:

```
   define(['text!views/viewtemplate.html'], function (template) { ...
```

Comment: We would need more code to help you better. Did you add `'text.js'` in the array of `files` served by Karma? (in your karma config)

Comment: @glepretre Thanks for your response, I got it working in the meantime  by following the hints given in this discussion https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/740

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue, too, as I was trying to bring mock JSON files into my test files and parse them with JSON.parse(requirejsInjectedJsonText).

The issue I had was forgetting to update my karma config file with the require-js-text and mock files:

```
files: [
  {pattern: 'mocks/**/*.json', included: false},
  {pattern:'lib/requirejs-text/text.js', included: false},
  'config/require.config.js'
]
```

After adding these in place (requirejs config reference must always be in the last index of 'files' array in the karma config file), I was able to successfully pull in my mock data.

For the record, as I was fiddling around, I went as far as @ddd in adding the shim to the require config, i.e.:

```
shim: {
  'text': {'exports': 'text'}
}
```

But, it turned out to be unnecessary after I removed it AND had the karma config setup as above.

Cheers!